# Websocket client with EMSCRIPTEN

Tags: javascript, c++, websocket, emscripten

is there a simple way to get a simple websocket client with EMSCRIPTEN?
Can someone provide me an example of EMSCRIPTEN code that connects to a websocket client?

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure it's worth an answer but I managed to find [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/emscripten-discuss/v1lzx5Ua_mI), which has links to a gist and a full project.